# Generate SHA1 (of Image) on iPhone? (Incorrect results)

Tags: iphone, ios, hash, sha

I have looked everywhere and cannot find a solution to my problem.  I have written a program for Android and Windows both that calculates the SHA1 hash of a given image.  I confirmed these hashes with HashCalc that I downloaded.  However when I try to do the same for iPhone I get a completely different hash.  I believe it has something to do with converting the image to a byte array before I compute the hash.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerCotroller:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[imageview setImage:image];

NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
NSString *hash = makeSHA1(imageData);

[filepath setText: hash];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


NSString* makeSHA1(NSData *data) {       

uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);    

NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];    

for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];    
return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem here is that you're converting the data using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`. Even if you started with JPEG data, there isn't a promise that this returns exactly the same bytes as you started with.

My (untested) suggestion is that you ask the `CGDataProvider` for the raw data. Something like this:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
if (imageData != NULL) {
  ...
  CFRelease(imageData);
}
```